# Kensington Trackball Works, how to scroll horizontally with Trackball or Auto Scroll

Tags: defaults, macos

I have a Kensington Expert Mouse on the Mac running the latest 1.3 drivers.

There still is no option to use the trackball to in addition to scroll vertically also scroll horizontally. Similar to the ball on the mighty mouse.

Has anyone found a hidden setting that I could enable with the defaults write command?

Comment: On a regular mouse shift/scroll-wheel is horizontal, by default - so presumably shift/scroll-ring would do the same...

Comment: Shift does help indeed. But that requires me to press an additonal key. Since I'm using the ball of the trackball for scrolling. I'd like to use it like the scroll ball of the mighty mouse.

Answer (score 3):

The old driver used to have an option to set a button (or button combination) to 'change scroll direction'.  I used to use that all the time and they have since gotten rid of it.

The workaround I've been able to come up with is to program a button to simply type the shift key (I use the two bottom button combination).  It's not as nice, but then you can hold the button(s) and scroll in the opposite direction without using your second hand.